# Post publish date

Tags: date, publish

if I have more than one posts that publish in the same day, `the_date()` function does not print publish date.

How can I fix it?

thanks

I solve this by: "`the_time(get_option('date_format'));`"

Comment: can you also add the relevant codes along with the question?

Answer (score 0):

For printing date of multiple posts you can use get_the_date fx

```
<?php echo get_the_date() ?>
```

> When there are multiple posts on a page published under the SAME DAY,
>   the_date() only displays the date for the first post (that is, the
>   first instance of the_date()). To repeat the date for posts published
>   under the same day, you should use `get_the_date` (since 3.0) with a date-specific format string.- WordPress Codex

Answer (score 0):

This is explained on the according [Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date):

```
echo get_the_date();
```